# Using an Int in a string?

Tags: basic4android

VERY new user here.
I'm playing with Basic 4 android and having fun.

Originally I wanted to do this
ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,thumb+".jpg")
which doesn't work

The following code works, but is there a more elegant way - I'm sure there must be.
Thanks in advance.
Steve

Sub Timer1_Tick
   'Handle tick events
   If thumb <17 Then
        thumb=thumb+1
        Else
        thumb=1
    End If

```
    Select thumb
        Case 1
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"1.jpg")
        Case 2
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"2.jpg")
        Case 3
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"3.jpg")
        Case 4
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"4.jpg")
        Case 5
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"5.jpg")
        Case 6
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"6.jpg")
        Case 7
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"7.jpg")
        Case 8
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"8.jpg")
        Case 9
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"9.jpg")
        Case 10
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"10.jpg")
        Case 11
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"11.jpg")
        Case 12
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"12.jpg")
        Case 13
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"13.jpg")
        Case 14
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"14.jpg")
        Case 15
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"15.jpg")
        Case 16
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"16.jpg")
        Case 17
            ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets,"17.jpg")

    End Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 3):

```
ImageView2.Bitmap = LoadBitmap(File.DirAssets, thumb & ".jpg")
```